# Android Wear Packaging

Tags: android, release, packaging, wear-os

I can't package my Android Wear app, when it's installed on phone, wear version are not on watch.

There is my gradle files (wear) :

```
buildscript {
dependencies {

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def versionMajor = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_MAJOR)
def versionMinor = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_MINOR)
def versionPatch = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_PATCH)
def versionBuild = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_BUILD)

android {
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    applicationId project.PACKAGE_NAME
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION_WEAR)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}.${versionBuild}"
    manifestPlaceholders = [watchfaceName: project.WATCHFACE_NAME, appName: project.APP_NAME]       
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("/Users/jimmy/Developer/keystore")
        keyAlias 'name'
        storePassword 'pw'
        keyPassword 'pw'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':submodules:watchface-gears:library')
    compile project(':commonlibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.+'
}
```

and mobile :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def versionMajor = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_MAJOR)
def versionMinor = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_MINOR)
def versionPatch = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_PATCH)
def versionBuild = Integer.parseInt(APP_VERSION_BUILD)

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId project.PACKAGE_NAME
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}.${versionBuild}"
        manifestPlaceholders = [watchfaceName: project.WATCHFACE_NAME, appName: project.APP_NAME]

    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/Users/jimmy/Developer/keystore")
            keyAlias 'name'
            storePassword 'pw'
            keyPassword 'pw'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':commonlibrary')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

And also my Manifest (wear):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.jaumard.skullface">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND"/>

    <application
            android:label="${appName}"
            android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.WatchfaceApp">
        <activity android:name="android.support.wearable.activity.ConfirmationActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/ConfirmTheme"/>
        <activity
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
                android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.activity.WatchfaceActivity"
                android:label="${watchfaceName}"
                android:taskAffinity=""
                android:allowEmbedded="true">

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview" android:resource="@drawable/preview"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
                android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.activity.DrawerActivity"
                android:label="${watchfaceName}"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
                android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.activity.DreamSettingsActivity"
                android:label="${watchfaceName}">

        </activity>
        <service
                android:name=".services.LauncherService"
                android:enabled="true">
        </service>
        <service
                android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.services.DataService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
                android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.services.DreamerService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Point to additional information for this dream (optional) -->
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.service.dream"
                    android:resource="@xml/dream" />
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.helpers.PackageReceiver"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And mobile :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.jaumard.skullface">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/preview"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:label="${appName}">
        <activity android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.activities.MainActivity"
                  android:label="${appName}"
                  android:icon="@drawable/preview"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.activities.DrawerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/home_drawer">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.activities.ClockActivity"
                  android:label="@string/home_clock">
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.DataListener" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="jaumard.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
                android:name="com.jaumard.skullface.services.DataService" android:exported="false"
                android:enabled="true">
        </service>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I don't understand why wear app is not installed...

EDIT : 
I can make it work by manually sign/package wear app or by modifing gradle file like this :

```
wearApp project(':wear')
wearApp files('../wear/build/outputs/apk/wear_release.apk')
```

Comment: How do you launch your build with gradle ? The WearApp is joined to the Handheld app only on signed release version.

Comment: Yes I launch it with release version. It's working when I package wear app manually or when I modify my  gradle file with :

    wearApp project(':wear')
    wearApp files('../wear/build/outputs/apk/wear_release.apk')

Comment: Usually how long does it take for the wear application to be installed after the launch of the mobile application on the phone, given that the mobile phone and the wear are connected?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you use release key for signing? You have to use it, debug keys don't work here.
2. Check your final apk file. If you properly included wear project to mobile, you should have android_wear_micro_apk.apk in your res/raw folder

Comment: 1. Yes I use release key
2. Yes I have android_wear_micro_apk.apk in your res/raw but no sync when install on phone. I make it to work (see my edit) but it's not the official way to do it

Comment: Could you try to pack app the same way as you did before and ff you will be able to see android_wear_micro_apk.apk in your res/raw folder then press Resync apps in Android wear app?

Comment: Do you use Android Studio to build release version?

Comment: I try Android Studio and IntelliJ but I prefer IntelliJ so just try few times on Android studio

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solve it with checking permissions.
Could you check that the wearable and mobile apps has exactly the same permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building with Android Studio using gradle, just make the wearable app as a module in your phone project. Then you have to make sure you have done the following configurations:

1. The phone manifest and the wearable manifest should declare exactly  the same permissions.
2. Ensure that both the wearable and handheld app modules have the same package name and version number.
3. When signing with the debug key, your wearable app will not be installed automatically by installing the phone app. You should manually install the wearable app on the wearable device via bluetooth debug.

Comment: "exactly the same permissions" I thought the wearable permissions should be a subset of the phone permissions.